# Regular Expression works fine in regextester but doenst work in R

Tags: regex, r

Seems like im missing something very simple here,

I have a regular expression that works as required in regex tester but when used in R it returns/matches nothing.

[image: Regex showing 2 matches on regextester]

**same regex when used in R doesnt match anything**
[image: fails in R]

it finds matches in R if i divide the regex into 2 parts one for finding correlation-id and other for finding connection-id,cant understand why they arent working when clubbed together.

1.`(?:\s+D\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+CORRELATION.*\=)([a-z0-9]+\_\w+)`

2.`(?:\s+D\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+CONNECTION.*\=)([A-Z]+)`

**To make it reproducible here is the regex and data.**

***Regex:***

`(?:\s+D\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+CORRELATION.*\=)([a-z0-9]+\_\w+)(?:\s+D\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+CONNECTION.*\=)([A-Z]+)`

***corresponding R code***

```
data <- readLines("data12.txt")

## Warning message:
## In readLines("data12.txt") : incomplete final line found on 'data12.txt'

check <- regexec("(?:\\s+D\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+CORRELATION.*\\=)([a-z0-9]+\\_\\w+)(?:\\s+D\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+CONNECTION.*\\=)([A-Z]+)",data)

matches <- regmatches(data, check)
```

***Data:***

```
M 8000000 NADR     14273 18:17:33.22 STC35256 00000291  DSNT375I  +HPN2 PLAN=DISTSERV WITH 024
D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli
D                                         024 00000291          CONNECTION-ID=SERVER
D                                         024 00000291          LUW-ID=G93FF023.DB11.CDD5C8DE241F=29839
D                                         024 00000291
D                                         024 00000291  THREAD-INFO=SAPHPNDB:9.63.240.123:SAPHPNDB:db2jcc_application:DYNAMIC
D                                         024 00000291  :46835:*:*
D                                         024 00000291          IS DEADLOCKED WITH PLAN=DISTSERV WITH
D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli
D                                         024 00000291          CONNECTION-ID=SERVER
D                                         024 00000291          LUW-ID=G93FF07C.EE5F.CDD5C82B2305=29799
D                                         024 00000291
D                                         024 00000291  THREAD-INFO=SAPHPNDB:9.63.240.33:SAPHPNDB:db2jcc_application:DYNAMIC:
D                                         024 00000291  46835:*:*
E                                         024 00000291          ON MEMBER HPN2
```

[image: same issue with grep]

Comment: Try to remove uneeded escapes before the `=` and before the `_`

Comment: Tried the same regex after removing the uneeded escapes before = and _but still the same issue.

Comment: Your datas seem to come from a tab separated file, In my opinion the way to go is to parse the file like this: http://www.portfolioprobe.com/user-area/documentation/portfolio-probe-cookbook/data-basics/read-a-tab-separated-file-into-r/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's time to talk about how to debug regex.

Regextester is GOOD! But you'll always be using it in a different environment, like you are currently. And then problems occur.

First of all, use grep or sub, their output is more intuitive.

Secondly, when you run into problems, find the very minimal regex and make it work. I'll make an example:

```
# take one line of the text and see if you can find a symbol
> grep('D', 'D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli')
[1] 1
# seems it works. now add a part of your regex and see if that works
> grep('\\s+D', 'D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli')
integer(0)
# it doesn't! lets try with a different part
> grep('D\\s+', 'D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli')
[1] 1
# this works. lets see what it actually matches by replacing with an asterix
> sub('D\\s+', '*', 'D                                         024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli')
[1] "*024 00000291          CORRELATION-ID=db2jcc_appli"
# ok, I can see from this how far the \\s+ reaches
```

And so on. Small steps :)

Comment: the above approach can be used  but it would take a lot of time, i just pasted a small snippet of the regex, the actual regex is written for the whole data from M till E.my primary concern is why the same code does not work in R, and moreover it works when divided but doesnt work as one regex.

Comment: Same thing happens even with grep, i could pull out the data in small chunks but a combined regex doesnt work, image updated above.

Comment: I'm giving you a way to find out how to make your code work with your data. Since it's a complex problem and complex data it's highly unlikely that anyone will just provide you with the correct solution. Learning the way to solve these things yourself is way more valuable and may also be the only way to solve this particular problem.

Comment: completely agree with u, i tried multiple methods but with this particular regex method seems like im very close to solving this if i could just figure out whats going wrong when it comes to handling the combined regex in R.